# Estoy teniendo problemas al llamar una method de una clase, dice que el method no es una funcion

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con objetos y clases y para un trabajo me pidieron crear una lista a partir de los elementos obtenidos de un form, llego a crear el objeto mediante la class Personas() pero al momento de ejecutar el method Agenda.agregarPersona() me tira un error diciendo que no es una funcion.

Estoy empezando con objetos y clases y para un trabajo me pidieron crear una lista a partir de los elementos obtenidos de un form, llego a crear el objeto mediante la class Personas() pero al momento de ejecutar el method Agenda.agregarPersona() me tira un error diciendo que no es una funcion.

```
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio() {
  document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", proceso)
let agenda = new Agenda();
}

function proceso() {
  personas(); // Personas hace referencia a la seccion "Personas" del comienzo

}

function personas() {
  let n = document.getElementById("idNombre").value;
  let s = document.getElementById("idSeccion").value;
  let m = document.getElementById("idMail").value;
  let p = new Persona(n, s, m); // creo a la persona
  console.log(p);
  Agenda.agregarPersona(p); // guardo a la persona en la agenda
  alert("holaaa");
  actualizarPersonas(); // actualizamos la lista de la seccion Personas
}

function actualizarPersonas() {
  document.getElementById("lista").reset();
  let lista = document.getElementById("lista");
  lista.innerHTML = ""; // vaciar la lista
  let datos = Agenda.darAgenda(); // obtenemos los objetos "personas" de la agenda mediante la funcion darAgenda()
  for (let i of datos) {  //  crear la lista con cada persona de la Agenda
    let nodoLi = document.createElement("li");
    let nodoTexto = document.createTextNode(i);
    nodoLi.appendChild(nodoTexto);
    document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(nodoLi);
  }
}
class Agenda {
    constructor() {
        this.lista = [];
    }
    agregarPersona(people) {
        this.lista.push(people);
    }
    darAgenda() {
        return this.lista;
    }
}

class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, seccion, mail) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.seccion = seccion;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estabas definiendo la variable `agenda` dentro de `inicio()`, por lo que no era visible en otras funciones. Hay que definirla en contexto global e inicializarla después.

El otro error que tenías era que tratabas de acceder a la variable con `Agenda`, pero ese es el  nombre de la clase y no puedes acceder al método porque no es estático (pero ese es otro tema); basta con usar la variable `agenda` (todo en minúsculas) para acceder a la instancia de la clase, propiedades y métodos.

Finalmente, al crear la lista, solo estabas enviando un objeto `Persona` en lugar de mostrar cada dato disponible.

```js
class Agenda {
    constructor() {
        this.lista = [];
    }
    agregarPersona(people) {
        this.lista.push(people);
    }
    darAgenda() {
        return this.lista;
    }
}

class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, seccion, mail) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.seccion = seccion;
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
let agenda;
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio() {
  document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", personas);
  agenda = new Agenda();
}

function personas() {
  let n = document.getElementById("idNombre").value;
  let s = document.getElementById("idSeccion").value;
  let m = document.getElementById("idMail").value;
  let p = new Persona(n, s, m); // creo a la persona
  console.log(p);
  agenda.agregarPersona(p); // guardo a la persona en la agenda
  actualizarPersonas(); // actualizamos la lista de la seccion Personas
}

function actualizarPersonas() {
  let lista = document.getElementById("lista");
  lista.innerHTML = ""; // vaciar la lista
  let datos = agenda.darAgenda(); // obtenemos los objetos "personas" de la agenda mediante la funcion darAgenda()
  for (let i of datos) {  //  crear la lista con cada persona de la Agenda
    let nodoLi = document.createElement("li");
    let nodoTexto = document.createTextNode(`${i.nombre} - ${i.seccion} - ${i.mail}`);
    nodoLi.appendChild(nodoTexto);
    document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(nodoLi);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="idNombre" placeholder="Nombre"><br>
<input type="text" id="idSeccion" placeholder="Sección"><br>
<input type="email" id="idMail" placeholder="Email"><br>
<button id="boton">Agregar</button>

<ul id="lista">
</ul>
```